Debug Assert Failed
I have been working for a couple weeks on getting a program written in c++ that uses winform, Excel API, and ADO to connect to a SQL19 Database. Now I wrote a simple .cpp file WITHOUT winforms that allows me to connect to the Database, I can successfully run the query and input the data into excel files and save them. Completely automated. I also created a very simple winforms application that has a couple of buttons, and takes the dates and adjusts the query to pull data based on which button the user clicks. Both the winform app that I made and the standalone app with the ADO connection and excel API in windows work perfectly with no issues. BUT as soon as add them to the same solution in Visual studios 2022, it gives a heap error. I am relatively new to all of this, so I feel this may just be a configuration issue. Plus, both programs work perfectly separate, so another reason I feel I have something misconfigured. The project was set up as a "CLR Empty Project(.NET Framework)".
The specific error is:
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
Line: 1059
Expression: _CtrlIsValidHeapPointer(block)
Code that is causing the problem:
#include "reportFunctions.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


//dynamic link library (DLL) is a collection of small programs that larger programs can load when needed to complete specific tasks
//Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (ADO) enable your client applications to access and manipulate data from a variety of sources.
#import "c:\\program files\\common files\\system\\ado\\msado15.dll" rename ("EOF","adoEOF") no_namespace//this is needed for using ADO to connect to the database. Make sure the file this dll generates files in is NOT read only. Otherwise this will say an error about cannot open something. 

//Import all the type libraries from office to be able to manipulate excel files.
#import "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Root\\VFS\\ProgramFilesCommonX86\\Microsoft Shared\\OFFICE16\\MSO.dll" \
    rename("RGB","RGB_mso") rename("DocumentProperties","DocumentProperties_mso") 

using namespace Office;

#import "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\vfs\\ProgramFilesCommonX86\\Microsoft Shared\\VBA\\VBA6\\VBE6EXT.OLB"

using namespace VBIDE;

#import "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE" \
    rename( "DialogBox", "ExcelDialogBox" ) \
    rename( "RGB", "ExcelRGB" ) \
    rename( "CopyFile", "ExcelCopyFile" ) \
    rename( "ReplaceText", "ExcelReplaceText" ) \
    exclude( "IFont", "IPicture" )

    bool isLeapYear(int aYear) {
        bool leapYear = false;
        int leapYears[26] = { 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012, 2016, 2020, 2024, 2028, 2032, 2036, 2040, 2044, 2048, 2052, 2056, 2060, 2064, 2068, 2072, 2076, 2080, 2084, 2088, 2092, 2096, 2100 };

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if (leapYears[i] == aYear) {
                leapYear = true;
            }
        }
        return leapYear;
    }

    int getEndDay(int aMonth, bool isLeapYear) {
        //december is excluded since if the month is 12, since if the if statements don't execute, then
        int jan = 1, feb = 2, mar = 3, apr = 4, may = 5, jun = 6, jul = 7, aug = 8, sep = 9, oct = 10, nov = 11;

        if (aMonth == jan) { return 31; }
        else if (aMonth == feb) {
            if (isLeapYear) { return 29; }
            else { return 28; }
        }
        else if (aMonth == mar) { return 31; }
        else if (aMonth == apr) { return 30; }
        else if (aMonth == may) { return 31; }
        else if (aMonth == jun) { return 30; }
        else if (aMonth == jul) { return 31; }
        else if (aMonth == aug) { return 31; }
        else if (aMonth == oct) { return 31; }
        else if (aMonth == nov) { return 30; }
        else  return 31;
    }
    //for the top button that runs the current months reports. 
    void runReports(int aMonth, int aYear) {
        
        //Variables and array used for DB manipulation:
        _ConnectionPtr connection;
        _CommandPtr command;
        _CommandPtr command2;
        _RecordsetPtr recordset;
        _RecordsetPtr recordset2;
        
        std::wstring monthNames[] = { L"January",{L"February"},{L"March"}, {L"April"}, {L"May"}, {L"June"}, {L"July"}, {L"August"}, {L"September"}, {L"October"}, {L"November"}, {L"December"} };
        int deptArray[] = { 6010, 6015, 6020, 6030, 6040, 6070, 6080, 6120, 6160, 6170, 6210, 6215, 6230, 6235, 6250, 6310, 6311, 6320, 6324, 6331, 6335, 6337, 6339, 6340, 6360, 6370, 6380, 6391, 6392, 6393, 6396, 6430, 6440, 6470, 7000, 7010, 7120, 7130, 7140, 7150, 7160, 7170, 7180, 7190, 7200, 7220, 7230, 7240, 7250, 7260, 7280, 7290, 7400, 7500, 8010, 8020, 8030, 8200, 8210, 8225, 8230, 8240, 8250, 8300, 8404, 8405, 8406, 8500, 8501, 8502, 8503, 8504, 8506, 8610, 8630, 8700 };

        //All of this is required for opening a connection and pulling data from the SQL Database. 
        //Initialize COM
        //Intialize the ADO Connection object
        connection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
        connection->Open(L"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source = SQL19\\redacted;Initial Catalog=redacted;User ID=redacted;password=redacted", L"", L"", -1);
            
        
        //This is a foor loop that will iterate for each element of the above array, depArray. This is where the data is collected, and inserted into excel files. 
        for (int i = 0; i < 76; i++) {
            //HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
            //HRESULT result;
            
            Excel::_ApplicationPtr pXL;
            pXL.CreateInstance(L"Excel.Application");
            pXL->Visible[0] = VARIANT_TRUE;
            Excel::_WorkbookPtr workBook = pXL->Workbooks->Add(Excel::xlWorksheet);//creates excel file, which comes with one worksheet.
            Excel::_WorksheetPtr worksheet1 = pXL->ActiveSheet; 
            worksheet1->Name = L"Dept Pay";
            pXL->Visible[0] = VARIANT_TRUE;
            //Intialize the ADO RecordSet object to get data from the finance database
            recordset.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
            
            //Intialize the ADO Command object
            command.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));
            
            //Assigns the command to the current db connection.
            command->ActiveConnection = connection;
            
            command->CommandText = _bstr_t(L"HCH.dbo.J_DeptPayCodeBreakdown");
            
            //Determine the date, is a leap year, and get the end date day, since each month varies in how many days are in each month, and we need that for the search parameters in the command. 
            bool leapYear = isLeapYear(aYear);
            int endDay = getEndDay(aMonth, leapYear);
            
            const std::wstring& beginningDateStr = std::to_wstring(aMonth) + L"/1/" + std::to_wstring(aYear);
            _variant_t beginningDate(&beginningDateStr);
            
            const std::wstring& endDateStr = std::to_wstring(aMonth) + L"/"+ std::to_wstring(endDay) + L"/" + std::to_wstring(aYear);
            _variant_t endDate(&endDateStr);
            
            command->CommandType = adCmdStoredProc;
            command->CommandTimeout = 15;
            command->Parameters->Append(command->CreateParameter(L"@Department", adInteger, adParamInput, 50, deptArray[i]));
            command->Parameters->Append(command->CreateParameter(L"@StartDate", adDate, adParamInput, 50, L"02/01/2024"));
            command->Parameters->Append(command->CreateParameter(L"@EndDate", adDate, adParamInput, 50, L"02/29/2024"));
            
            //Commit or run the command.
            recordset = command->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdStoredProc);
            _variant_t fieldCount = recordset->Fields->Count;
            int limit = (int)fieldCount + 1;
            fieldCount = (short)0;
            short iterator = 0;
            Excel::RangePtr cell = worksheet1->Cells;
            
            for (int x = 1; x < limit; x++) {
                cell->Item[1][x] = _bstr_t(recordset->Fields->GetItem(&fieldCount)->Name);
                fieldCount = (short)++iterator;
            }
            
            worksheet1->Range[L"A2"]->CopyFromRecordset(recordset);////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            
            //Closes the recordset. 
            recordset->Close();
            
            const std::wstring& pathStr = L"C:\\Excel_Dump\\MyExcels\\" + std::to_wstring(deptArray[i]) + L"_" + monthNames[aMonth - 1] + L"_" + std::to_wstring(aYear) + L".xlsx";
            
            _variant_t path(&pathStr);
            //saves and closes the worksheet.
            
            workBook->SaveAs(path, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, false, false, Excel::XlSaveAsAccessMode::xlShared, false, false, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing);///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            
            workBook->Close();
            //closes the excel application. 
            pXL->Quit();
        }
        connection->Close();
        //Uninitialize COM        
        CoUninitialize();
    }


I have deleted and started a new project. I have changed the configuration in visual studio for this project by right-clicking on project, and going to > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library, and changed this to Multi-Threaded Debug DLL(/MDd). It was originally on Multi-Threaded DLL(/MD). No change. This code above works perfectly when I created another project that does not have winforms involved. Very frustrating.

Is this really C++ or is it C++/CLI?  It's the #import statement that's bothering me.

I recommend using a table for the "days per month" and make an exception for February.  It's simpler than an if-else-if ladder or switch.

In which version of Visual Studio was your old WinForm project compiled? You pointed out /MD, does your project mix release and debug?

Namespaces exist for a reason so do not use #import with no_namespace  so you can avoid the rename too. And you do NOT need to project to be clr/cli (that's for interaction with .Net, and you're using COM). Leapyear stuff should be handled by std;:chorno::is_leap or by a calculation (not looking up some limited array). last day of month...

Make you depth array an std::vector and avoid raw loops like for(int i = 0; i < 76; ++i). E.g. std::vector<int> values{0,1,2}; and then a range based for loop for (int value : values).  All in all it looks like you where never taught how to use C++ properly

Since I asked this question, I have isolated the issue to the runReports() function.That same exact code works just fine when I run just it in an empty C++ project(No .NET Framework involved). I've looked up Heap errors, and I don't know where to even start troubleshooting with that. Do you have any idea what the difference is between an empty project and a "CLR Empty Project(.NET Framework)" that may cause the heap error? And thank you all for the input so far. Much appreciated.

The error indicates line 1059. Which line in your code jumps to the error code line?
The code you provided is a snippet and involves runtime errors, so we cannot run and reproduce your error. Please modify your code according to the above comments first.

Also see the similar thread  `1
Run using application verifier.. This is a tool which checks for correctness the code which is running.`

Last night I recreated the GUI in wxwidgets instead of visual studios winforms, and the error went away completely. Not a solution to the issue, but a workaround. It was pretty nice having the design window for the GUI that winforms provided.
